# Java Coin Counter Quarters/Dimes/Nickels/Pennies

Tags: java, class, int, driver, system.out

I've been having trouble with this one program I'm trying to run.

This lab will investigate the problem solving and programming behind such machinery.

You always want to use the fewest coins possible. You should use integer mathematics to solve this problem.

Provide the number of cents through the constructor. Write a method that calculates the number of each type of coin.

tl;dr
I need to count coins in a certain amount of cents.

so far, I have this:

```
public class P4_Icel_Murad_Coins_java{
    private int c;
    public P4_Icel_Murad_Coins_java(int coins){
        c = 94;
        int Q_i, D_i, N_i, N_f;
    }

    public void counter(){
        int Q_i = (int)(c % 25);
        int Q_f = c - (Q_i * 25);
        int D_i = (int)(Q_f % 10);
        int D_f = c - (D_i * 10);
        int N_i = (int)(D_f % 5);
        int N_f = (int)(c - (N_i * 5));

        System.out.println("Quarter(s): " + Q_i );
        System.out.println("Dime(s): " + D_i);
        System.out.println("Nickel(s): " + N_i);
        System.out.println("Penny(ies): " + N_f);               

    }
}
```

And my Driver class is

```
public class Driver_class
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P4_Icel_Murad_Coins_java start = new P4_Icel_Murad_Coins_java(94);
        start.counter();
    }
}
```

I am getting really odd numbers that include negatives in the answer, and alot of pennies for some reason.
Any help will be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: The line `int Q_i, D_i, N_i, N_f;` is meaningless, you don't need all the casts to `int`, and you ignore the `coins` parameter in the constructor.

Comment: The `coins` parameter should really be named `cents`, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, Andreas is right. The task says it: "Provide the number of cents through the constructor." And it says: "You should use integer mathematics to solve this problem." How can 94/25=260? or the next time 94/25=179?

Comment: @dev.null for the end product I got 260, sorry I didnt clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use divide "/" instead of modulo "%". E.g.

```
int Q_i = (int)(c / 25);
```

And you should correct your constructor, which didn't use the coins from caller:

```
public P4_Icel_Murad_Coins_java(int cents){
    c = cents; // here use the caller cents
}
```

Comment: when I replace the % with / i get 179 instead of 94, thanks for responding btw :)

Comment: How can you get 179 when you divide 94/25?

Comment: Have you replaced all occurrence of % with /?